# ORA-02067: transaction or savepoint rollback required

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently trying to merge data from a local table that is identical via a database link. However i am receiving a ora-02067: transaction or savepoint rollback required. I did some googling and found out that the fix was to rollback after the transaction but don't think rolling is a plausible solution in this situation since i want to write data and have it committed in the other table.  How do i need proceed? Below is my merge code: thanks in advance:

```
MERGE INTO db1.IN_DATA@ora Y
USING
    (SELECT DISTINCT FROM,
            TO,
          "DATE_",
          TIMESTAMP_, 
            VAL,
            LOCAL_TIMESTAMP,
            LAST_UPDATE
    FROM    IN_DATA
  ) X ON (
            Y.FROM = X.FROM
            AND Y.TO = X.TO
            AND Y.TIMESTAMP_ = X.TIMESTAMP_)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
      SET Y.VAL                = X.VAL,
       Y.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP = X.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT 
            (
          FROM,
          TO,
          DATE_,
          TIMESTAMP_,
          VAL,
          LOCAL_TIMESTAMP,
          LAST_UPDATE)
       VALUES   
         (X.FROM,
          X.TO,
          X.DATE_,
          X.TIMESTAMP_,
          X.VAL,
          X.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP,
          X.LAST_UPDATE);
```

Comment: Hi @John, i googled your error, please check if there is any lock on the "IN_DATA" table in remote database. if it is there please kill the session and rerun you query.

Comment: hmmm there doesnt seem to  be a lock currently and when i checked when i was getting those messages, i dont see any data being inserted in... i'm going to kill my session and restart it.

Comment: Have you tried committing this transaction? Have there been any changes to the remote table since you started this statement?

Comment: can we commit across a database link? wouldn't they have to do that on their side?